# Is there a way to upgrade android studio in linux?

Tags: android-studio

I have android studio `version  0.4.2` and want to upgrade it to `version 0.8.9`. I am using ubuntu. In linux there is no installer for android studio. So, I downloaded the android studio `version 0.8.9`.
 Now should I just run the `studio.sh` file in the bin directory? Are there any precautions that I have to take? How do I make sure that this act as an update rather than just running a new android studio (what about my previous workspace, dependencies etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version (Preview) uses `~/.AndroidStudioPreview` to store the configs. Starting 0.8 the configs are saved in `~/.AndroidStudioBeta`.

After first start, the new version will ask to import from old install. Point it to `~/.AndroidStudioPreview` and you'll be good to go.

Comment: There is an error - Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (19.0.3) is too low for project ':app'. Minimum required is 19.1.0

Comment: So, go upgrade your SDK.